# dump with old 43BSD,question about tape size

Tags: bsd, dump

On old 43bsd i want to dump /usr

This command works

```
dump 0uf /dev/rmt12 /dev/ra0a
```

dump is command 0u mean full and update /etc/dumpdates f mean use /dev/rmt12
and /dev/ra0a is the root partition.
The problem is when i want to dump the /usr wich is big,and tape is see as small tape,but is big enough to contain /usr.
The question is: how to pass the size option?
I have tried

```
dump 0ufs56000 /dev/rmt12 /dev/ra0g
dump 0us5600f/dev/rmt12 /dev/ra0g
dump 0us5600f /de/rmt12/dev/ra0g
```

And all fail.
I want to pass the 5600 size to dump,how to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found
First rewind tape

```
mt rewind
```

then pass arguments as this

```
dump 0udsbf 54000 6000 126 /dev/rmt12 /dev/ra0g
```

for 2GB 4mm tape

```
#2g tape
54000     #density
6000      #size
126       #block factor
```